# Manim 'coords_to_point' new version

Tags: manim

I am looking for something like the defunct `'coords_to_point'` in the new `manim` version (2021).

What do you replace `coords_to_point` with?

```
from manimlib import *

class DiagramPlot(Scene):
def construct(self):
    data = [20, 0, 0, -5]
    x = [0, 8, 38, 39]
    
    dot_collection = VGroup()
    for time, val in enumerate(data):
        dot = Dot().move_to(self.coords_to_point(x[time], val))
        self.add(dot)
        dot_collection.add(dot)
    l1 = Line(dot_collection[0].get_center(), dot_collection[1].get_center())
    l2 = Line(dot_collection[1].get_center(), dot_collection[2].get_center())
    l3 = Line(dot_collection[2].get_center(), dot_collection[3].get_center())
    self.add(l1, l2, l3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `axes.c2p(*your_point)` with `axes` being the `Axis()` object.  the c2p method returns the point for your coordinates as numpy array.